# Why's my media query appearing in the chrome dev tools when it has already been deleted?

Tags: html, css, debugging

I've encountered this strange behavior where inside my media query in my CSS file, I deleted the CSS selector along with the declarations properties which means they shouldn't show up in dev tools anymore.

However, when I navigate back to the browser and open up dev tools, that CSS is still there.

an example to demonstrate what I'm saying:

below is what's currently live inside my CSS file.

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
 .container {
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

however, in dev tools this is what's appearing:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
   .form-inline .form-control {
      display: inline-block;
      width: auto;
      vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

I tried cmd + shift + f5 but that didn't work as well as other things but to no avail.  How can I fix this?

Comment: make sure the page is reloading

Comment: Clear your cache

Comment: @DCR yes my page is indeed reloading

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava tried that already, didn't work.  I just don't understand what's going on, this is blowing me away.

Comment: In case you are using bootstrap, that media query is a default bootstrap one, which you might need to override. I don't think that `.form-inline .form-control` and `.container` are the same elements in your code. So when you select any of them only the corresponding one would show.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava ah I see what you mean, I was just thinking the same thing actually.

Comment: So is your problem solved?